# WP Cron job running but not executing the full function

Tags: php, wordpress, api, youtube, cron

So i'm making a plugin that uses the youtube V3 api to bring videos from our youtube channel and turns them into posts for our site.

I'm using WP Cron for this. Basically every 12 hours it checks to see if there are any new videos, if there are new videos them it uses the YouTube V3 API to turn them into posts.

Everything seems to be working fine except for one thing, which is when WP calls the cron job, the full function does not happen.

It should be pulling in about 4 videos. It only pulls in one.

Also for some reason the iframes that it puts the videos in inside fo the page don't show up.

But when I call the cron job manually using the Cron Manager Plugin 
"Advanced Cron Manager" everything works as it should.

I can confirm that the function works.

I can also confirm that when I tell wordpress to run the cron job that it works.

Its only when WP decides to run the cron job by itself that the function does not work. It does run. And it does do some of what the function should do, just not everything.

So my question is not so much "why is the youtube api not working" or "why is my cron job not running", But why would a wp cron job work when manually called but not when wp calls it?

Comment: Try to dump log when cron happens to see if everything is working fine or not, make sure to enable WP_DEBUG to get errors and warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not only WP, it can happen in any framework. It's more like a generalized question. Here is what I propose you do:

1. Check your error logs. maybe you are having memory limit issues. If its the case, make sure you have memory_limit set something high like 256 or 512M.
2. Put various custom log messages in your function and record it into a separate log file so that you at least know till where it runs and where it stops.
3. Whatever requests you make to external apis like youtube, put it in to a try catch block to catch any exceptions and log them too.

Hopefully you will can debug it that way, good luck!